# Finding a text string with jQuery in table

Tags: jquery, html

I have this script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var search = 'foo';
    $("table tr td").filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() == search;
    }).parent('tr').css('background-color','#f2dede');
});
```

What I want it to do is to color the background of the table whether the text is "foo" or "supfoo" or "foobar" or "foo foo".  Anything with "foo" in it should be colored pink.

Not sure what to change!  Please help...

Comment: A regex is probably better here than `==`

Comment: I'd probably just use `$(this).text().indexOf('foo') > -1` for this.

Comment: Thanks, nurdyguy!  That worked just as I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Could you use :contains()?

```
$( "tr:contains('foo')" ).css( "background-color", "red" );
```

Comment: You'd want to be careful that you aren't overly broad.  This checks *every* `tr`.  But yes, this general approach could work well.

Comment: @nurdguy, I was banking on him knowing what he was doing.  The slightest inkling of jQuery knowledge tells you this selects every TR.

Comment: I agree. I just wanted to give him a heads up before he pastes the code in somewhere and all heck breaks loose.